# C# WCF Azure common on different role

Tags: c#, wcf, azure-sql-database

In Azure, I have one WebService role and one WorkerRole. In one case, I wanna use a lock, to avoid parallel processing on specifics methods. In classic, I should use lock feature:

```
lock (obj)
{
    // code
}
```

But the object need to shared between roles. Is it possible ? If not how I should proceed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is called [distributed lock manager](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_lock_manager).

One way to implement this in azure is [using blob storage](http://blog.smarx.com/posts/managing-concurrency-in-windows-azure-with-leases) (bit outdated post).
Of course there are tons of other ways. But probably you want to rethink your architecture and use azure queues/topics or something else.